# How does ordering a hstore attribute works in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

In my database there is a "News" model with a hstore attribute "title", which provides a title in multiple languages like this:

```
{
  "de": "Beispiel Titel",
  "en": "example title"
}
```

When I build a Query like `News.all.order({ "title" => "desc"})` it works. Can Someone explain how it works under the hood?